# iPad keyboard appears in wrong orientation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

I have a splitView Application that has a rootViewController and DetailsViewController
When the application loads the detailsViewController pops a Modal viewController that contains a UINavigationBar.

The UINavigationBar has a search bar on it (set programatically). When focus is brought to the search bar the keyboard pops-up.

However, depending on the orientation of the device (simulator) the keyboard pops-up in the wrong orientation. The keyboard is always displayed as if the ipad is in a 'normal' orientation (i.e. at the side the home key is at)

I am returning **YES** in all of the shouldAutoRotate Methods:

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

To try and find out what was happening i added some debug code to each class to log the `interfaceOrientation` each time the shouldAutorotate event is fired while also showing when the modal `viewDidLoad` method fired. I did a test for each orientation: the debug output is shown below.

**The debug shows that regardless of the actual device orientation, the rootViewController and DetailsViewController interface orientations are always Portrait**.

The only correct logs (where interface orientation = device orientation) are the first and last(3rd) time the modal shouldAutorotate events are fired in each test.

If I rotate the iPad after the app has launched then the keyboard appears in the correct orientation.

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening and how to avoid it?

> [PORTRAIT]
>
> Home Button Position: bottom
>   Keyboard Appears: bottom
>
> DEBUG:
>
> APP DELEGATE- ADD SPLITVIEWCONTROLLER
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL DID LOAD
>   MODAL-ROTATE START
>   MODAL-ROTATE END
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>
> [LANDSCAPE]
>
> Home Button Position: left
>   Keyboard Appears: left
>
> DEBUG:
>
> APP DELEGATE- ADD SPLITVIEWCONTROLLER
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface LANDSCAPE
>   MODAL DID LOAD
>   MODAL-ROTATE START
>   MODAL-ROTATE END
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface LANDSCAPE
>
> [PORTRAIT]
>
> Home Button Position: top
>   Keyboard Appears: top
>
> DEBUG:
>
> APP DELEGATE- ADD SPLITVIEWCONTROLLER
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL DID LOAD
>   MODAL-ROTATE START
>   MODAL-ROTATE END
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>
> [LANDSCAPE]
>
> Home Button Position: right
>   Keyboard Appears: right
>
> DEBUG:
>
> APP DELEGATE- ADD SPLITVIEWCONTROLLER
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   ROOT-Interface Portrait
>   DETAIL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface LANDSCAPE
>   MODAL DID LOAD
>   MODAL-ROTATE START
>   MODAL-ROTATE END
>   MODAL-Interface Portrait
>   MODAL-Interface LANDSCAPE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to let iOS handle the rotation event before presenting the modal view controller.

Here's what's happening:

1. The app is launched.
2. Based on the device's orientation, a screen rotate event is queued for existing view controllers.
3. Before the screen rotate appears, your new view controller is created with the *existing* orientation from the view controller.
4. The screen rotate event is handled.
5. Your new view controller animates into existence with the wrong orientation.

It's basically a UIKit race condition. Some of these details are speculation, but the effect is obvious.

Luckily, this is **really easy** to fix.

Instead of creating your new view directly, schedule it to be handled on the main queue. It'll get done after the current events are dispatched, which include the rotation event.

Current:

```
[self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

Fixed:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
});
```

With this new code, you get this sequence instead:

1. The app is launched.
2. Based on the device's orientation, a screen rotate event is queued for existing view controllers.
3. Before the screen rotate appears, the code to create your new view controller is queued but not executed.
4. The screen rotate event is handled.
5. Your new view controller is created with the *correct* orientation from the view controller.
6. Your new view controller animates into existence with the right orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the orientations you support into the plist?

See:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH6-SW9